# Python can't find extension on Windows

Tags: python, windows, setuptools

i wrote a python extension myExtension and put it inside a package myPackage. In the package **init** I put the line :
import myExtension

I install the package using setuptools:

```
setup(...     
      packages=['myPackage'], 
      ext_modules=[Extension("my package.myExtension")]
```

)

When I install it on Linux "import myPackage" works perfectly but when I do the same on Windows I get an ImportError: module myExtension doesn't exists

Any thought why this is happening? And how can I fix this

Comment: can't you install it with `pip install` on windows?

Comment: Apparently `easy_install myPackage` works but then again what if the machine I am using doesn't have setuptools?